# ionic ios simulator not scrolling (Android ok)

Tags: android, ios, scroll, ionic2

I am new to ionic and setup a simple test app with a couple lists.  I launched in the ios simulator and it wouldn't scroll - there wasn't even any feedback to suggest it understood the UI interaction.  It worked fine in the android simulator.

I worked it out and I wanted to put this out there for any others in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS (simulator) to scroll you need to click-scroll (at least on my 2015 Macbook Pro trackpad).  And on Android (simulator) a touch-scroll is all that is required.

I'm sure this is a case of RTFM. :)